# jquery index() of section

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery sortable on div containing a number of section elements. I would like to use index() to output position of each section.

index() only returns value for the first section but it can't locate the second one (or third, fourth etc.)

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code:

```
    <div id="existingquestions" class="sortable">
            <section class="question" id="question_777">
                <p id="positionof_777"></p>
                <p class="questiontext">question.text</p>
                <script>$(document).ready(function() {
                            var qpos = Number($('.sortable > section:visible').index('#question_777')+1);
                            $('#positionof_777').html(qpos);
                        });
                </script>
            </section>
            <section class="question" id="question_888">
                <p id="positionof_888"></p>
                <p class="questiontext">question.text</p>
                <script>$(document).ready(function() {
                        var qpos = Number($('.sortable > section:visible').index('#question_888')+1);
                        $('#positionof_888').html(qpos);
                    });
                </script>
           </section> 
    </div>
```

The other function that I'm using works just fine although it's basically the same as above:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').placeholder();
        $(".sortable > section:visible").hover(function() {
            var index = $(this).index()+1;
            $("#example_index").html("Index " + index);
        });
    });
```

I'm clueless. What am I doing wrong in the first example?

Comment: What happens? What's the error? What works?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RWsnS/ Seems to put "1" in the position just fine. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @veredesmarald - I just edited my question putting some more explanations there. Sorry if my message wasn't clear at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as you desired:

```
<div id="existingquestions" class="sortable">
  <section class="question" id="question_777">
    <p id="positionof_777"></p>
    <p class="questiontext">question.text</p>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var qpos = $('.sortable > section:visible#question_777').index() + 1;
            $('#positionof_777').html(qpos);
        });
    </script> 
  </section>
  <section class="question" id="question_888">
    <p id="positionof_888"></p>
    <p class="questiontext">question.text</p>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var qpos = $('.sortable > section:visible#question_888').index() +1 ;
            $('#positionof_888').html(qpos);
        });
    </script> 
  </section>
</div>
```

### **[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zS4JX/3/)**

#### Note

You don't need `Number` to conversion, `.index()` always return a number.